# How to iterate through my List of Strings

Tags: haskell

Ive got some serious problems to finish a project for university and ive got no clue how to work with haskell.

I need to parse a FEN-String to smth i can work with.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List.Split

startFEN = "rnbkqbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBKQBNR"


splitFENString :: String -> [String]
splitFENString = splitOn "/" 


workONstring :: [String] -> [String]
workONstring = let e = splitFENString in
                map (nvcls) 


nvcls :: [Char] -> [Char]
nvcls [] = []
nvcls ('1':xs) = nvcls ('0':xs)
nvcls ('2':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':xs)
nvcls ('3':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':'0':xs)
nvcls ('4':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':'0':'0':xs)
nvcls ('5':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':'0':'0':'0':xs)
nvcls ('6':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':'0':'0':'0':'0':xs)
nvcls ('7':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':'0':'0':'0':'0':'0':xs)
nvcls ('8':xs) = nvcls ('0':'0':'0':'0':'0':'0':'0':'0':xs)
nvcls (x:xs) = x : nvcls xs
```

i want to use `nvcls` on every string in the list, but i have no clue, how to satisfy the compiler...

Comment: what does nvcls mean?  you probably want to write `'0' : nvcls xs` etc.

Comment: i want to convert this: ["rnbkqbnr","pppppppp","8","8","8","8","PPPPPPPP","RNBKQBNR"]
to this:
["rnbkqbnr","pppppppp","00000000","00000000","00000000","00000000","PPPPPPPP","RNBKQBNR"]
its a representation of a chessboard

Comment: What is a FEN string? What are you trying and what should it do and what errors do you get?

Comment: Are you looking for the `map` function?  e.g. `map nvcls ["1", "2"] == ["0", "00"]`

Comment: so map a function which does the transformation.    `f :: String -> String  \\  f "8" = "00000000"  \\ f x = x`

Comment: yes im looking for the function, which is spliting the FEN-string and maping  my nvcls function on it afterwards. 
in ghci it seems pretty easy:
let e = splitFENString startFEN  ......
map nvcls e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change the workONstring function like this

```
workONstring :: String -> [String]
workONstring = map nvcls . splitFENString
```

then you can call for startFEN

```
workONstring startFEN
```

Comment: maybe if we change function this way make more sense `workONstring s = map nvcls (splitFENString s)`